# [Error]: AWS credentials are not found in current profile. - ask-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ask-cli

After setting up AWS profile using ask-cli (ask init) I used ask clone command to get my skill. Everything worked pretty fine. After I wanted to upload the changes via:

```
ask lambda upload -f arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxx:function:test -s .
```

I got the error that AWS credentials are not found in current profile. What did do I wrong ? Is there something special to know ? Permission in IAM are also set for admin.

I hope anyone can help. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have not initialized the AWS command line before using Ask-cli.

First install the AWS Command Line Interface on your device using the following link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

Once done please use **aws configure** command to set up a profile. It will ask you for AWS Access Key ID, AWS Secret Access Key, Default region name and Default output format.

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: *******your key*********
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: *******your key************
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: json
```

To get AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key do the following :

- Open the IAM console.
- In the navigation pane of the console, choose Users.
- Choose your IAM user name (not the check box).
- Choose the Security credentials tab and then choose Create access key.
- To see the new access key, choose Show. Your credentials will look something like this:

  Access key ID: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE

  Secret access key: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

To download the key pair, choose Download .csv file. Store the keys in a secure location.

Once set up do the following :

- Run **ask init**
- Select default profile, hit enter.
- use arrow keys to select default AWS profile you just created.
- It will lead you to amazon.com login page on your browser.sign-in there and your AWS profile will be assigned with your ask-cli.

Now you are ready to use any ask-cli command which also makes changes to your AWS services.

Note: You can initialize multiple AWS and ask profiles on one device. for this use :

- **$ aws configure --profile user2** to create a new aws command line
  profile.
- Then run **ask init** again.
- create a new profile and assign your new aws profile to it.
- Then to use any ask-cli command on this
  new ask-cli profile, use **--profile profileName** as the suffix of each
  ask-cli command. for example :

  **ask clone --profile secondUser**